# SQL Database Function if/then

Tags: sql, if-statement, supabase, supabase-database

In my supabase database, I have a list of words along with their uuids in the form of

| uuid | word | unique_chars | found_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | apple | 4 | 0 |
| y2 | banana | 3 | 0 |

I want to return all words, which contain a specific letter – say `"E"` (called "main char") – and a defined set of 6 other letters (`charone` to `charsix`) from the table. Each word can (but does not have to) have the other letters; however, it must not have any letter which was not defined before (`charone` to `charsix`) Therefore, I tried using an SQL Database Function like this:

```
create or replace function get_possible_words_t2(mainchar text, charone text, chartwo text, charthree text, charfour text, charfive text, charsix text)
returns setof dict
language sql
as $$
  select *
  from dict
    where word ILIKE (mainchar); --HAS TO INCLUDE MAINCHAR IN WORD 
    -- if charone == A = true -> skip | if charone == A = false -> and not word ilike ('%a%')
$$;
```

I can not make the if/then part work. I want to include the line `and not word ilike ('%a%')` only if charone is *not* equal to A. Can someone help me with the syntax? Which ever way I try, it's not working...

Comment: The tag `supabase` says: "..... It uses the **PostgreSQL** database ...." Why do you tag `sql-server` and not `postgresql` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have this data:

```
CREATE TABLE words (
   word VARCHAR(200),
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO words VALUES
   ('apple',1),
   ('banana',2),
   ('pear',3),
   ('Pineapple',4);
```

And these 2 functions:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS cnt1(s VARCHAR(200), t varchar(200));
CREATE FUNCTION cnt1(s VARCHAR(200), t VARCHAR(200)) RETURNS INTEGER
  AS 'with RECURSIVE cte as (
  select 0 as x, $1 as y, $1 as z 
  union all 
  select x+1,y,substring(y,x+1,1) from cte  where  x<length($1)) 
select count(distinct(z)) from cte where x>0 and position(z in $2)>0;'
 LANGUAGE SQL;
```

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS cnt2(s VARCHAR(200));
CREATE FUNCTION cnt2(s VARCHAR(200)) RETURNS INTEGER
  AS 'with RECURSIVE cte as (
  select 0 as x, $1 as y, $1 as z 
  union all 
  select x+1,y,substring(y,x+1,1) from cte  where  x<length($1)) 
select count(distinct(z)) from cte where x>0 ;'
 LANGUAGE SQL;
```

You can do:

```
SELECT
   word,
   cnt2(word) unique_chars, 
   cnt1(word, 'charone') found_count
FROM words;
```

| word | unique_chars | found_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 4 | 2 |
| banana | 3 | 2 |
| pear | 4 | 3 |
| Pineapple | 7 | 3 |

And `apple` has 4 unique characters, and 2 of them (`a` and `e`) are in `charone`.

NOTE: I hope this comes close to your requirements...